# Select All / Unselect All option in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is it possible to have the 'Select All / Unselect All' option in react-select?
Is this something that is built in, or I have to do it my self?

Comment: https://react-select.com/home

Comment: You can try [this implementation](https://medium.com/@alex_escalante/react-select-alloptionoptions-with-a-single-click-1ebf5a33fe31)

Answer (score 36):

At the company where I work we've made a wrapper around `react-select` with some additional features and styling. One of the features is Select/Unselect All.

Here is a link to page that demoes the component:

https://topia.design/components/multi-select/

Here is the approach that I've used to implement Select/Unselect All:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-panini-8458i?file=/src/MultiSelect.js

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactSelect from "react-select";

export const MultiSelect = props => {
  // isOptionSelected sees previous props.value after onChange
  const valueRef = useRef(props.value);
  valueRef.current = props.value;

  const selectAllOption = {
    value: "<SELECT_ALL>",
    label: "All Items"
  };

  const isSelectAllSelected = () =>
    valueRef.current.length === props.options.length;

  const isOptionSelected = option =>
    valueRef.current.some(({ value }) => value === option.value) ||
    isSelectAllSelected();

  const getOptions = () => [selectAllOption, ...props.options];

  const getValue = () =>
    isSelectAllSelected() ? [selectAllOption] : props.value;

  const onChange = (newValue, actionMeta) => {
    const { action, option, removedValue } = actionMeta;

    if (action === "select-option" && option.value === selectAllOption.value) {
      props.onChange(props.options, actionMeta);
    } else if (
      (action === "deselect-option" &&
        option.value === selectAllOption.value) ||
      (action === "remove-value" &&
        removedValue.value === selectAllOption.value)
    ) {
      props.onChange([], actionMeta);
    } else if (
      actionMeta.action === "deselect-option" &&
      isSelectAllSelected()
    ) {
      props.onChange(
        props.options.filter(({ value }) => value !== option.value),
        actionMeta
      );
    } else {
      props.onChange(newValue || [], actionMeta);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ReactSelect
      isOptionSelected={isOptionSelected}
      options={getOptions()}
      value={getValue()}
      onChange={onChange}
      hideSelectedOptions={false}
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      isMulti
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All other answers are sloppy and do not cover all edge cases like this one

Comment: this work pretty well with react-select.
I'm trying a similar scenario for `react-select-async-paginate`, hmm

Comment: for typescript please refer the below link demo: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-erapo7?file=README.md) source:[link](https://github.com/kalaiy/react-select-all) https://github.com/kalaiy/react-select-all

Answer (score 11):

I  inspired from [Alex](https://medium.com/@alex_escalante/react-select-alloptionoptions-with-a-single-click-1ebf5a33fe31)'s method, but i changed some section of his code. There is a [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-ellis-kgw39) i prepared, if you still need, you can check.

And also I made another [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-night-05pwq?fontsize=14) for the case that there is too much data, i solved performance problem with react-window and i changed input value if user select more than 5 items.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for react-select@5.2.0  (achieves "select all" option gracefully")
(remove TypeScript parts to run in pure jS)

```
const MultiSelect: React.FC<MultiSelectProps> = ({
  options,
  defaultValue,
  onChange,
}) => {
  const selectAllOption = { label: 'select all', value: '*' };

  const initialVisibleOptions =
    options.length === defaultValue?.length
      ? options
      : [...options, selectAllOption];

  const [availableOptions, setAvailableOptions] = useState<Option[]>(
    initialVisibleOptions,
  );

  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState<readonly Option[]>(
    defaultValue,
  );

  const relayOnChange = (newSelectedOptions: readonly Option[]) => {
    const selectAllIsSelected = !!newSelectedOptions.find(
      o => o.value === selectAllOption.value,
    );

    const newComponentState = selectAllIsSelected
      ? {
          selectedValues: options,
          availableOptions: [],
        }
      : {
          selectedValues: newSelectedOptions,
          availableOptions: initialVisibleOptions,
        };

    setSelectedValues(newComponentState.selectedValues);
    setAvailableOptions(newComponentState.availableOptions);
    onChange(newComponentState.selectedValues);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      isMulti
      options={availableOptions}
      value={selectedValues}
      defaultValue={selectedValues}
      onChange={relayOnChange}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For any others interested, Inspired by the answer from @Mihhail Lapushkin I created a typed version using Next.js and Typescript. React-Select gets a little finicky with SSR and SSG, so it requires additional ids. See the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/nswagg/MultiSelect-TS/csb-uov6l8/draft/long-snow?file=%2Fcomponents%2FSelect.tsx) for the live demo or over on [GitHub](https://github.com/nswagg/MultiSelect-TS)
Reusable component looks something like this:

```
import { ActionMeta, Options } from 'react-select';
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useRef } from "react";

import Select from 'react-select';
import makeAnimated from 'react-select/animated';

const animate = makeAnimated();

interface Props {
  options: Option[]
  selected: Option[],
  setSelected: Dispatch<SetStateAction<any>>,
  title: string,
  hide?: boolean
}

export type Option = {
  value: number | string;
  label: string;
};

/* Advanced Dropdown Select Menu using React select
 * Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250357/20007391 and 
 * added typing.
 * 
 * For more information about the react-select API, options, and 
 * customization, see https://react-select.com/home
 * 
 * This component is just the select box. Options are passed in from 
 * the parent and the parent maintains the state of the object for 
 * callbacks and function handling. */
export default function MultiSelect(props: Props) {
  // For component "memory"
  const valueRef = useRef(props.selected);
  valueRef.current = props.selected;
  
  const selectAllOption = {value: "*", label:"Select All"};
  const isSelectAllSelected = () => valueRef.current.length === props.options.length;
  const isOptionSelected = (option: Option, selectValue: Options<Option>) => 
    valueRef.current.some(({value}) => value === option.value) ||
    isSelectAllSelected();

  //const getOptions = () => isSelectAllSelected() ? [] : [selectAllOption, ...props.options];
  const getOptions = () => [selectAllOption, ...props.options];
  const getValue = () => isSelectAllSelected() ? [selectAllOption] : props.selected;

  const handleSelect = (newValue: unknown, actionMeta: ActionMeta<unknown>) => {
    const {action, option, removedValue} = actionMeta;
    // Reassigning for typing. Unknown by default
    const opt = option as Option;
    const removed = removedValue as Option;
    if (action === "select-option" && opt.value === selectAllOption.value) {
      //console.log("new item selected");
      props.setSelected(props.options);
    } else if ((action === "deselect-option" && opt.value === selectAllOption.value) || (action === "remove-value" && removed.value === selectAllOption.value)) {
      props.setSelected([]);
      //console.log("all items removed");
    } else if (actionMeta.action === "deselect-option" && isSelectAllSelected()) {
      props.setSelected(
        props.options.filter(({ value }) => value !== opt.value));
        //console.log("new item removed");
    } else {
      props.setSelected(newValue || []);
      //console.log("new item added");
    }
    //console.log(action, newValue, getValue());
  }

  return (
      <Select
        isOptionSelected={isOptionSelected}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        defaultValue={getOptions()} // Should default to select all option
        value={getValue()}
        isMulti
        //isSearchable
        //components={animate}
        placeholder={props.title}
        options={getOptions()}
        onChange={handleSelect}
        hideSelectedOptions={props.hide ?? false}
        instanceId={props.title}
        id={props.title}
      />
  )
}
```

The only sticky thing comes from defining what your options look like. You can format your options to be the same or define a generic and setup a type guard to type check the unknown values (default for ActionMeta<> and newValue in react-select). Console Logging added for convenience and demo purposes