# How to have multiple react-select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-select so that users can select multiple options from the dropdown menu however I want to be able to use multiple react-select in my application.

I have this in the constructor

```
class OrderForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: [],
    };
  }
```

Here is the handleChange function

```
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption }, () =>
      console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedOption)
    );
  };
```

How would I implement this so that I can for example have 3 select options like this:

```
  <Select
   options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    placeholder="Choose your first mix"
    isSearchable
    isMulti
  />

  <Select
   options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    placeholder="Choose your second mix"
    isSearchable
    isMulti
  />

  <Select
   options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    placeholder="Choose your third mix"
    isSearchable
    isMulti
  />
```

At the moment when I update one select, all of them get updated. I know it's because of the function however I'm not sure how to create one where the value of the specific select is stored in the state.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions. One is you could create multiple handleChange functions, one for each selector. Each one could set a different piece of state. If you need to update the same array using multiple selectors, you'd need a little more complicated logic to push/pull from the single array by checking if the value already exists in the array.

Honestly for something like this I would recommend using a form and giving each selector a unique name, not sure if you're familiar but Formik makes stuff like this pretty easy, by handling the onChange stuff automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could have three (or any number of) flavor options and then set them separately:

```
this.state = {
  selectedOptions: [],
};


handleChange = index => selectedOption => {
    const updatedOptions = this.state.selectedOptions.map((o,i)=>i===index?selectedOption:o)
    this.setState({ selectedOptions:updatedOptions });
  };

<Select
   options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption}
    onChange={this.handleChange(0)}
    placeholder="Choose your first mix"
    isSearchable
    isMulti
  />

<Select
   options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption}
    onChange={this.handleChange(1)}
    placeholder="Choose your second mix"
    isSearchable
    isMulti
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prop `name` of the `Select` component and access it using the second argument of the `onChange` method as below.

You also better to do some changes in your state structure for this:

```js
this.state = {
      selectedOption: {
         first: {},
         second: {},
         third: {}
      }
};
```

```js
   
  <Select
    options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption.first}
    name="first"
    ...
  />

  <Select
    options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption.second}
    name="second"
  />

  <Select
    options={flavours}
    value={selectedOption.third}
    name="third"
    ...
  />
```

```js
 handleChange = (value, action) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: {
        [action.name]: value
      } 
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

React-Select already supports multiselect. It appears that you are implementing 3 separate forms when you may only need one component, since you have the `isMulti` option included. If you are using 3 different sets of options, you will want to handle them differently with different states. Having 3 separate input forms to handle one multi-select is a bit redundant. From the documentation, this would allow you to pick multiple items in one form.

Further, it is recommended you transition to React functional hooks if possible. This will make handling your state significantly easier.

```
import React from 'react';

import Select from 'react-select';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

export default () => (
   <Select
      defaultValue={[colourOptions[2], colourOptions[3]]}
      isMulti
      name="colors"
      options={colourOptions}
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
   />
);
```

If you are looking for a select all kind of option, check out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001629/select-all-unselect-all-option-in-react-select/73748176#73748176]