# How to select all options in react select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am not able to implement select all option for react select.
Below is my code

Here I am using react-select with multi select option.

when I click on select all option it should select all options in the dropdown and save it in a state variable.

```
import React from "react";
import Select,{components} from 'react-select';
import '../App.css'

const options = [
    { value: '*', label: 'Select All' },
  { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', color: '#0052CC', isDisabled: true },
  { value: 'purple', label: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
  { value: 'red', label: 'Red', color: '#FF5630', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange', color: '#FF8B00' },
  { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow', color: '#FFC400' },
  { value: 'green', label: 'Green', color: '#36B37E' },
  { value: 'forest', label: 'Forest', color: '#00875A' },
  { value: 'slate', label: 'Slate', color: '#253858' },
  { value: 'silver', label: 'Silver', color: '#666666' },
];

export default function ReactSelect() {
  const [value,setValue]=React.useState([])

  const  handleChange = (val) => {
    
    if(val && val.length && val[0].value==='*'){
        let arr=options;
        arr.splice(0,0);
        setValue([...arr])
    }
    else{
    setValue( [...val] );}
  }
  return (
    <div id="select">
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen </p>
      <Select
    onChange={handleChange}
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={options}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    components={{ ValueContainer }}
    value={value}
  />
  <button onClick={()=>console.log(value)}>CLick</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  let [values, input] = children;
  if (Array.isArray(values)) {
    const val = (i= Number) => values[i].props.children;
    const { length } = values;
    switch (length) {
      case 1:
        values = `${val(0)} `;
        break;
      default:
        
        const otherCount = length - 1;
        values = `${val(0)}+ ${otherCount} `;
        break;
    }
  }
  return (
    <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
      {values}
      {input}
    </components.ValueContainer>
  );
};
```

I tried to implement with select all option but its not working. Is there any inbuilt facility for it or any other select library which has multi select option with select all facility.

Comment: Have you looked @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001629/select-all-unselect-all-option-in-react-select?